# Releasing a file held by IIS

Tags: iis, wix

We have a WiX installer that during upgrades sometimes requires system reboot due to a file that is held in use by an un-named process (the log file doesn't show the holding process name)

Our guess is the IIS holds the file so we authored ServiceControl elements to stop IIS services.

```
<Component Id="RestartIis" Guid="{XXXXXXXX}" Transitive="yes">
    <CreateFolder />
    <ServiceControl Id="RestartIis" Name="IISADMIN" Start="both" Stop="both" />
    <ServiceControl Id="RestartW3SVC" Name="W3SVC" Start="both" Stop="both" />
</Component>
```

Still, the file gets held in use.
We tried adding RestartResource element to shut down w3wp process to no avail:

```
<util:RestartResource Id="w3wp1" ProcessName="w3wp.exe" />
```

The problem only occurs on our CI server

Has anyone encountered this before? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: don't guess. get told exactly which process is holding the file, e.g. use sysinternal's [handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) tool.

Comment: Tried that with unlocker- by the time I run it the file is no longer being held in use